# Switching from Eclipse 64 bit to Eclipse 32 bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, java, eclipse

Can I use same workspace and eclipse settings in 32 bit Eclipse that I used in 64 bit Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and you can use the same workspace on Linux/ OS X / Windows as well. The workspace is system agnostic (though there are some settings, like JVMs and libraries, which might need tweaking. It's possible for specific projects to have custom classpaths or other system specific settings that might need to be updated as well after you load the workspace up on the new system).